# Spring MVC binding overriding value attribute on form input

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a form which posts data to an Enquiry object. The Enquiry object is a ModelAttribute in the Controller which has no explicitly defined constructor. Despite setting the value attribute of the `age` input element to empty string in my form, it comes through as zero. This makes me think it's getting the existing value of `age` from the Enquiry object, which we be initialised to zero. Is there a way to still post to `enquiry.age` but not show the current value of it on my page?

My form

```
<form:form commandName="enquiry" method="post" action="mycontext/jsp/enquiry-search">
    <form:input path="name" value=""/>
    <form:input path="age" value=""/>
</form:form>
```

Part of my controller

```
    @RequestMapping( value = "/enquiry/{screenType}", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
@ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK )
public String getEnquiryScreen(@ModelAttribute ("enquiry") Enquiry enquiry, @PathVariable("screenType") String screenType) {

    return "enquiry";
}

@ModelAttribute( "enquiry" )
public Enquiry getEnquiry() {
    return new Enquiry();
}
```

My Enquiry class

```
public class Enquiry {

private String name;
private int age;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Thats not how model attributes work.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args)

Your form in effect does nothing, if you make enquiry a modelattribute.

I would have two methods, one for get and one for post, the POST can then take Enquiry as a method argument with ModelAttribute annaotion. This will ensure the object is poluated fro the requests and not the method annoated with model attribute - which just instantiates a new instance.